# Cannot find module 'browser-window' with nightmare and nodejs

Tags: node.js, nightmare

I'm having hard time to run nightmare from nodejs. I started with the example provided in the README, tried different version of electron-prebuilt and different tweaks but I'm always getting node that can't find the browser-window module.
Here is my test :

```
> node --version
v5.3.0
>
> cat .\package.json
{
  "name": "webautomation",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "testing nightmare.js",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nightmare": "^2.1.2",
    "vo": "^1.0.3"
  },
  "author": "ECH",

  "license": "ISC"
}
>
> npm install
>
> npm ls electron-prebuilt
webautomation@1.0.0 D:\MyEnv\WebAutomation
└─┬ nightmare@2.1.2

  └── electron-prebuilt@0.35.4
>
> cat .\main.js
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
console.log("require done");
dream = Nightmare();

dream.goto('http://yahoo.com');
dream.end();
>
> node main.js
creation done
module.js:338
    throw err;
    ^


Error: Cannot find module 'browser-window'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:286:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous>    (D:\MyEnv\WebAutomation\node_modules\nightmare\lib\runner.js:6:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm missing here ?

Comment: You might be missing `browser-window` module? Try doing `npm install --save-dev browser-window` and then running `main.js` again

Comment: From what I understand browser-window is an electron module that should be provided by electron-prebuilt. Indeed npm show browser-window returns a 404.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem with my app and I think its because there was a change in the API or so. Anyway, what I did to fix it was this:

In the main.js file, I replaced the old line

```
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
```

with this

```
var BrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
```

and then it worked.
You could refer to the thread here: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/404